# How to highlight lines in Atom Editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm aware of the different abilities to highlight based on filetype, but what I'm looking for is something similar to how in a typical text editor you can **highlight a line** (not just change the color text).

Is this possible to do in the Atom editor? If so, how do you do it? Is there a plugin for this?

The reason I want to do this is for organizational purposes, and sometimes the files I am working in our custom files that are not necessarily code but documentation (usually both are together in the same file), **and the documentation part is where I want to add these highlights**.

Comment: I may have found something here but not sure how to use it yet (https://github.com/atom/decoration-example)

Comment: found some more info here, https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.3.2/Decoration, but still not sure how to use this?

Comment: anyone know how to use the decorations api?

Answer (score 0):

The only Atom package I know of that has a somewhat similar functionality is the [bookmarks](https://atom.io/packages/bookmarks) package.

It is an Atom core package, so you most likely have it installed already.

It might not be exactly what you were looking for, since it only allows setting bookmarks on lines of your open files.
As soon as you close a file, the bookmarks are lost.
But while working on several opened files, it can be very useful to quickly navigate through these bookmarks.

The reason why no package like you asked for exists, probably is that it would be really hard or at least impractical to implement.
Imagine you set dozends of highlights on a file which is under version control (git, svn, etc.) and then pull in a newer version of this file where several lines were added, removed, changed, shifted ...

To still be able to show the highlights on the correct lines, the information of such highlights would need to be under the same version control. Essentially you would need to store this highlight on the line itself, which would mean everybody had the same highlights, which is probably not what you want. Because if you wanted that, you could just format your documentation with markdown or similar in the first place ;)